# Webpack 2 loading, exposing, and bundling jquery and bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, webpack, webpack-2

This has been asked in piecemeal but no one seems to be able to settle on an answer. 
I'm very simply trying to bundle jquery THEN bootstrap and have `$`, `JQuery` and `bootstrap` be exposed globally.

Here's my webpack.config.js

```
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        accountdetails: './src/main/webapp/public/js/accountdetails.js',
        vendor_jquerybs: ['jquery', 'bootstrap']
    }
    ,
    module:{
        loaders: [{
            test: /\.jsx?$/,
            exclude: /node-modules/,
            loader: 'babel-loader'
        }]
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.jsx']
    },
    output: {
        path: __dirname + '/src/main/webapp/public/js/dist',
        publicPath: '/',
        filename: '[name].bundle.js'
    },
    devServer: {
        contentBase: './dist'
    }
};
```

This bundles properly.  It loads as my first `<script>` in the `<head>`
But I get console issues like: "$ is not defined", "jQuery is not defined".

How do I write this config to expose jQuery/$ and bootstrap globally?  The Webpack docs say, `CommonChunksPlugin`, `expose-loader`, etc.  What is the best way to do this?  I'm very confused by the documentation.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer here https://github.com/webpack-contrib/expose-loader

the module is `expose-loader` and is apparently needed to expose objects, classes, etc to window.

```
module: {
  rules: [{
          test: require.resolve('jquery'),
          use: [{
              loader: 'expose-loader',
              options: 'jQuery'
          },{
              loader: 'expose-loader',
              options: '$'
          }]
      }]
}
```

NOTE: Correct me if I'm wrong, but there is then no need to expose bootstrap globally.  jQuery will suffice.

Full config now:

```
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        accountdetails: './src/main/webapp/public/js/accountdetails.js',
        vendor_jquerybs: ['jquery', 'bootstrap']
    }
    ,
    module:{
        loaders: [
            {
            test: /\.jsx?$/,
            exclude: /node-modules/,
            loader: 'babel-loader'
            },
            {
            test: require.resolve('jquery'),
            use: [{
                loader: 'expose-loader',
                options: 'jQuery'
                },
                {
                loader: 'expose-loader',
                options: '$'
                }]
            }
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.jsx']
    },
    output: {
        path: __dirname + '/src/main/webapp/public/js/dist',
        publicPath: '/',
        filename: '[name].bundle.js'
    },
    devServer: {
        contentBase: './dist'
    }
};
```

NOTE: You CANNOT remove 'jquery' from entry point.

Comment: In my case, I didn't need to expose bootstrap globally (plugins) either.  My mistake was that I was only exposing `$` when the plugins also needed `jQuery`.